# How do I install drop bars on my trek earl?

Tags: handlebars, conversion

I'm new to doing bike stuff, but I want to install drop bars on my single speed 2012 Trek Earl, how would I go about doing so? What things would I need to take into account before getting started?

Answer (score 1):

Bars of the correct diameter and new brakes.  But since that frame was designed for flat bars drop bars will put you really low.

Comment: +1 You should try riding with your stem slammed and your bar flipped to give you an idea of what drops will be like.